# Merging CSV tables with Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm trying to join CSV files containing stock indexes with Ruby, and having a surprisingly hard time understanding the documentation out there. It's late, and I could use a friend, so go easy on me:

I have several files, with identical headers:

```
["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"]
```

I would like my ruby script to read each "Date" column, and write to a new CSV compiling an all encompassing date range from the earliest date to the latest.

Bonus:
Ideally, I would like to add all of the other column data ("Open", "High", etc.) into this new CSV file, split by a column simply containing the following CSV's filename for reference.

Thanks for any consideration given to this. What I'd really like to do is sit down with a Ruby sensei to help me make sense of the documentation. How can I use the CSV.read() or CSV.foreach() do |x| methods to create arrays / hashes to perform upon?

(Theoretical and intelligent responses welcomed)

hypothetical:

```
CSV.read("data/DOW.csv") do |output|
    puts output
end
```

returns:

```
[["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"], ["2014-07-14", "71.35", "71.52", "70.82", "71.28", "823063.0"], ["2014-07-15", "71.32", "71.76", "71.0", "71.28", "813861.0"], ["2014-07-16", "71.34", "71.58", "70.68", "71.02", "843347.0"], ["2014-07-17", "70.54", "71.46", "70.54", "71.13", "1303839.0"], ["2014-07-18", "71.46", "72.95", "71.09", "72.46", "1375922.0"], ["2014-07-21", "72.21", "73.46", "71.88", "73.38", "1603854.0"], ["2014-07-22", "73.46", "74.76", "73.46", "74.57", "1335305.0"], ["2014-07-23", "74.54", "75.1", "73.77", "74.88", "1834953.0"]]
```

How can I identify rows, columns, etc? I'm looking for methods or ways to transform this array into hashes etc. Honestly, an overarching theoretical approach would suit my needs.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: It should be really helpful if you provide a sample data and expected output.

Comment: I've been reading the documentation and playing in irb to try and get my bearings to no avail. CSV.read("path/to/csv") puts my data into arrays, and CSV.foreach("path/to/csv") outputs data to a string. I'm trying to call some familiar methods like .first on the output of the array and getting the same output. I'm trying to find some function out of the CSV class and understand ways to manipulate specific rows/columns. If I knew how to navigate the output given from a CSV in an array of column or row specific arrays, I could take my next step

Comment: Can you try rephrasing the requirement and Bonus section with the output example?

Comment: The apprentice will achieve enlightenment by [consulting the options `new` accepts](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new). If processed headers one wants, processed headers one must request.

Comment: Thanks @colinm after reading the source code, and using fresh eyes, I've reached my solution. Your answer was great, and honed my focus on a part of the doc I should be paying attention to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been playing with Ruby and CSV most of this day, I might be able to help (even though I am beginner myself) but I don't understand what do you want as output (little example would help).

This example would load only columns "Date", "High" and "Volume" into "my_array".

```
my_array = []
CSV.foreach("data.csv") do |row|
  my_array.push([row[0], row[2], row[5]])
end
```

If you want every column try:

```
my_array = []
CSV.foreach("data.csv") do |row|
  my_array.push(row)
end
```

If you want to access element of array inside array:

```
puts my_array[0][0].inspect #=> "Date"
puts my_array[1][0].inspect #=> "2014-07-14"
```

When you finally get what you want as output, if you are on Windows you can do this from command prompt to save it:

```
my_file.rb > output_in_text_form.txt
```

Comment: +1 I find this simpler than mine. However you still need to explain how you'd give the output CSV file.

Comment: thanks! once he gives exact example of what he wants, I might be able to do more :/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'csv'

input = ARGV.shift
output = ARGV.shift

File.open(output, 'w') do |o|
  csv_string = File.read(input)
  CSV.parse(csv_string).each do |r|
    # r is an array of columns. Do something with it.
    ...
    # Generate string version.
    new_csv_row = CSV.generate_line(r, {:force_quotes => true})
    # Write to file
    o.puts new_csv_row
  end
end
```

- Using files is optional. You can use shell redirection and directly read from STDIN and/or directly write to STDOUT.